# Objective C++: Call Objective C method from C++

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurl, objective-c++

I'm using NSURLSession to connect to a database.
 I have this already implemented in C++ for Windows and am trying to get it working on iOS also.
 I have a .h file derived from a base C++ class that is the header for my .mm file.
 If I'm correct I have to implement all the functions in my .h file in C++. 
However NSURLSession is an Objective-C function. 
How do I call an Objective-C method from my C++ function?

I have a C++ function called Connect() where I make a C++ object m_Delegate that has an alloc and init.

```
this->m_Delegate = [[PrivateNSURLSessionDelegate alloc] initWihParent:this];
//where PrivateNSURLSessionDelegate is the name of my interface.
```

That interface has -(bool)NSConnect (with implementation in the @implementation) which I'm trying to call from:

```
void Connect()
{
    [PrivateNSURLSessionDelegate NSConnect];
    //This however gives me the error: +[PrivateNSRLSessionDelegate NSConnect]: unrecongnized selector sent to class
}
```

I also tried it using my C++ object

```
void Connect()
{
    [m_Delegate NSConnect];
    //This gives me a error that is unrecognized selector sent to instance
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I basically want to ask the Objective-C to do all the NSURL stuff and send just the data back to the C++.

I'm completely new to Objective-C so any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but have you made sure to set the extension of your Objective-C++ class to `.mm`?

Comment: I triple checked this. Lol. It is a .mm :).

Answer (score 2):

```
-(bool)NSConnect
```

Here the `-` indicates it is an instance method. Conversely `+` would indicate a class method.

That being said, `[PrivateNSURLSessionDelegate NSConnect];` calls a class method, since you call it on the interface `PrivateNSURLSessionDelegate`.
However, this is not defined as it is defined as `NSConnect` is defined as an instance method (btw the convention is that (instance) methods always start with a lowercase).

```
[m_Delegate NSConnect];
```

Does however call the instance method. You should define `-(bool)NSConnect` in the header file of `PrivateNSURLSessionDelegate`, not above the `@implementation` in the implementation file, that makes in a private method and thus inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Oops. Didn't mean to press "enter".
So I want an instance method, which then should be -(bool)NSConnect which should be in the @implementation? And I have it defined as such in the @interface. Is that correct? Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: Yes that sounds correct. See for example the [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-objective-c-classes-objects) tutorial, especially the part on implementation files. The answer by @gnasher729 maybe more in line with your c++ problem though..

Comment: I think that how I did it, but I'm still getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" - maybe it has something to do with the way I'm making the m_Delegate object?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been reading that tutorial and it is really good!

Answer (score 0):

There is Objective-C, which is a superset of C, and Objective-C++, which is a superset of C++. Objective-C++ source code files have a .mm suffix, where Objective-C would have a .m suffix.

You cannot call Objective-C from C++. You can however call Objective-C from Objective-C++, and you can write your usual C++ classes in Objective-C++ as well.

Comment: Okay, cool! Thanks for the clarification. I guess what I'm trying to do it call an Objective-C method from Objective-C++.

Comment: Objective-C++ is not a superset of C++. Objective-C++ allows you to mix C++ with Objective-C code, otherwise they are completely separate. For example, you cannot inherit from C++ in Objective-C and vice-versa.